# Debug Edge on HoloLens

Tags: windows, debugging, microsoft-edge, hololens

I'm currently working on a WebApp. This app should also be usable on a Microsoft Holo Lens.

Therefore I need Webdebugging for the HoloLens. 
Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this?

There Is no option on the WindowsDevicePortal (as far as I know).

And with the Edge DevTools Preview Remote Option I'm getting this error message:

> Could not connect to remote device. Retrieving tab list failed with code 404

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue with Xbox

Comment: unfortunately not. We didn't proceed with this project for other reasons

Comment: Same issue on Xbox. Absolutely no way to debug a `WebView`. The devtools preview app seems to be abandonware and hasn’t kept up with updates to the device portal.